# NBA rule - how far does the ball have to go in the hoop to count for points?

Tags: basketball, nba

Say the ball goes in halfway past the rim, and an opponent knocks the ball back upwards and out. Does this count for points? How far does the ball have to pass the rim to count as a successful score?

Comment: Another interesting question, if the ball goes partially in the hoop, then somehow rolls out on it's own, is this a bucket, or no?

Comment: @New-To-IT Even more interesting to hear how that could happen? Laws of physics is hard to beat.

Comment: @New-To-IT I'm imagining the ball is rotating clockwise, falling down and to the right, then hitting the right edge of the rim so that its rotation would push the ball up. If the ball is spinning fast enough it could get out of the hoop

Answer (score 6):

That would be illegal and considered interference.

From NBA rule 11, section I

> A player should not :
>   b. Touch any ball from within the playing area when it is above the basket ring and within the imaginary cylinder.
>
> g. Touch the ball at any time with a hand which is through the basket ring.
>
> i. Touch the rim, net or ball while the ball is in the net, preventing it from clearing the basket.
>
> PENALTY: If the violation is at the opponent’s basket, the offended team is awarded two points, if the attempt is from the two point zone and three points if it is from the three point zone. The crediting of the score and subsequent procedure is the same as if the awarded score has resulted from the ball having gone through the basket, except that the official shall hand the ball to a player of the team entitled to the throw-in. If the violation is at a team’s own basket, no points can be scored and the ball is awarded to the offended team at the free throw line extended on either sideline. If there is a violation by both teams, no points can be scored, play shall be resumed by a jump ball between any two opponents in the game at the center circle.

[NBA rules 2014-2015](https://turnernbahangtime.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/2014-15-nba-rule-book.pdf)

Comment: What is the punishment for interference in this case? Does the shooter get the points, or is it a free throw or something else?

Comment: @Fillet It depends on where it happens. I edited in the penalty